# Doubts during Partition

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, system-installation

I need to dual boot my pc with windows as main OS and Ubuntu as secondary OS.
During the installation the Ubuntu installation wizard prompted me to create partitions on HDD of 500 GB. I created a partition of 87 GB. After that it said that it would erase all data in the HDD. I'm afraid that it would erase windows. But I want both of them to boot. How can I achieve that without erasing windows?

Comment: If it is wanting to erase Windows, it is not correctly seeing the NTFS partitions. You must turn fast start up off in Windows. http://askubuntu.com/questions/843153/ubuntu-16-showing-windows-10-partitions UEFI install  Windows 10
https://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-alongside-a-pre-installed-windows-with-uefi